# how to get value of a specific grepped pattern using awk

Tags: perl, shell, unix, awk, sed

Looking out to get value of X_RULE only.  My input file might have patterns like

```
TMP_LEARN A B 
-antmove [ X_RULE = "STUDENT" ]
-antmove [ X_CLASS = "COMMERCE" ]
-antmove [ X_DISCRIPTION = "COLLEGE STUDENTS" ]
...
...


TMP_PROP -antmove [ X_RULE = "STUDENT" ] -antmove [ X_CLASS = "SCIENCE" ]  .....
```

Simple

```
grep "X_RULE" inputFile |awk -F " " '{print $1}'
```

will return correct results for first pattern but won't work on second pattern. How can I use

```
regex( i.e -- (/^\s*\[\s*X_RULE\s*=\s*([^\]]+)\]) ...)
```

on shell to segregate the value in this case?

Regards,
Divesh

Comment: are you looking to collect/print out all occurances within the file?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I just wish to get the value of X_RULE which in above case is STUDENT for both the patterns. In my actual file, value of X_RULE will be unique in each pattern. thanks@divesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this common regex for both lines of input in `grep -oP`:

```
grep -oP 'X_RULE\s*=\s*"\K[^"]+' file

STUDENT
STUDENT
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
X_RULE  # match literal text X_RULE
\s*=\s* # match = surrounded by optional spaces on each side
"       # match starting double quote
\K      # match reset to forget what we've matched so far
[^"]+   # match 1 or more of anything that is not " to get desired value
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified anubhabva's example as per my requirements and got what I exactly needed.

```
grep X_RULE $i | grep -oP 'X_RULE\s*=\s*"[^"]+' | awk -F " " '{print $3}' | sed -e 's/\"//' | sort -u >> tmp_a.list
```

Again, thanks a lot anubhava for your quick help.

Regards,
Divesh